# AssertionError: [E923] - Spacy error faced on CLI when training the model for NER

Tags: spacy-3

AssertionError: [E923] It looks like there is no proper sample data to initialize the Model of component 'tok2vec'. To check your input data paths and annotation, run: python -m spacy debug data config.cfg and include the same config override values you would specify for the 'spacy train' command.

The error comes precisely when I am training the model for NER using the command - python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./train.spacy

I have also removed tok2vec tag in base config file and still it fails.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for the spacy discussion forum: https://github.com/explosion/spacy/discussions. Please post the full config as part of the question.